# Is simple products image required

Tags: configurable-product, cart, swatches, ce-1.9.2.2

Are simple product images for each color and size required for correct cart view of product selected? Is there an easier way to associate correct color ordered to be visible in cart than uploading an image for each color and size or a product?

Answer (score 1):

In magento,there are two options to show image at cart for a configurable.

- **One show configurable product  image**
- **anthor configurable`s  simple product image which  have cart.**

Which manage from `admin ->System -> Configuration ->Sales -> Checkout -> Shopping Cart ->`

[image]

For question,**i can say that there are no way to show  correct cart   image view of product for a configurable  with out load  simple product image** .

If you want to   put any  logic then you need to customization.

Answer (score 0):

The core module for configurable swatches is quite limited. <del>You can only use simple product images for the swatches, so if you have one generic image for each color, you need to upload it all over again.</del> You can actually add generic color swatches like this:

Name the files the same way as the attribute option label, but lower case and with hyphens ("Sky Blue" => "sky-blue.png") - it has to be a PNG. Upload them to `media/wysiwyg/swatches`.

I recommend you the free alternative by @Marius, https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher where you can upload arbitrary swatch images per attribute option.

You can even use hex color codes instead of images:

[image: screenshot]